# How to use large amount of conditions with Wordpress Forms?

Tags: wordpress, forms

I'm using Wordpress to make an online register system for a friend. He needs a form with lots of conditional fields. In case, its about cars. The user will choose one car brand from a dropdown list.

So, when the car brand was chosen, a new dropdown appears below, with the car brands options, like the models. The, when the user choose a model, a third dropdown will be shown with the model versions.

Example:

Brand: Porshe
Model: Carrera
Version: GT

But I have lots of car brands with lots more of models and versions.

I was trying to use CONTACT FORM 7 CONDITIONAL FIELDS, but the plugin only works with 250 itenns. I read in a forum that I will need a "script" to work with these great amount of conditions.

How can I solve it? 
Is there any WP option?
The script works with CF7?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." You need to do the proper research and see if you can find any plugin that does what you want. If you can't find any, you'll need to build your own.

Answer (score 0):

GravityForms is doing a really good job with conditional logic inside of a form. You can even add dynamic calculation fields ;-) 
It's not free but it's absolutely worth its price.

I used it for a few projects now and never had any problems with the conditional logic.

https://www.gravityforms.com/

Cheers Dominik